# Magento capture all emails

Tags: event-observer, api, email, ee-1.13, send-mail

I'd like to capture all email events in Magento before they're sent and prevent magento from sending them.
I know I can disable all emails under `system > mail sending settings`, but this is not enough. I want to send data from that email to another system.
Something like this:

- Magento wants to send email
- Some method captures the email
- Same method prevents magento from sending the email
- Same method sends data through api to another system

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know about the `enterprise edition` but I am pretty sure that there is no event in `ce`

You can achieve this functionality by rewriting this classes

`Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template` and `Mage_Core_Model_Email`

In both class you find `send` method you need to rewrite the send method. as below

```
public function send($email, $name = null, array $variables = array())
{ 
   Mage::dispatchEvent('email_template_send_before', array('email' => $this, 'email_to' => $email));
   $return = parent::send($email, $name, $variables);
   Mage::dispatchEvent('email_template_send_after', array('email' => $this, 'email_to' => $email));
   return $return;
}
```

after rewrite this way now you have two events
 `email_template_send_before` and `email_template_send_after`